# TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\Python\Second Shot - Classes.py", line 159, in <module>
    d = Demonstrator("####.csv")
  File "C:\Users\####\Python\Second Shot - Classes.py", line 142, in __init__
    self.reader.run()
  File "C:\Users\####\Python\Second Shot - Classes.py", line 97, in run
    self.counter.add( Rectangle(theme, channels, owing, status, mark, code))
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'channels', 'owing', 'status', 'mark', and 'code'
```

I understand its normally because I have call a class without giving it a argument but I'm not seeing it here? i dont understand where i need to be putting the positional arguments given in the error. The code takes a .csv and i use the information in the function add to give me a result. The arguments are the columns in the .csv im working with.

```
 from rect import Rectangle
 class Counter():
       def __init__(self):
          self.count  = 0
          self.area   = 0
          self.Top3 = 0
          self.finalVal = 0
          self.TotalOwing = 0
          self.Columnbounter= {}

       def add(self, rectangle):
          if rectangle.getTheme() in self.Columnbounter:
             self.Columnbounter[rectangle.getTheme()]+=1
          else:
             self.Columnbounter[rectangle.getTheme()]=1
          self.popularDict= sorted(self.Columnbounter, key = self.Columnbounter.get, reverse = True)
          self.Top3 = self.popularDict[:1]

       def question1(self):
          return ("Question 1, Most Common String: %d " %(self.Top3))

       def reset(self):
          self.count  = 0
          self.area   = 0
          self.Top3 = 0
          self.finalVal = 0
          self.TotalOwing = 0
          self.Columnbounter= {}

    ##-------------------
    ## FileReader class
    ##--------------------
    class FileReader():

       def __init__(self, filename, counter):
          self.counter = counter
          self.filename = filename

       def run(self):
          theFile = open( self.filename,'r')
          firstLine = True

          for line in theFile:
             if firstLine: 
                  firstLine = False
                  continue

             line=line.strip()
             fields=line.split(",")
             theme= str( fields[0])
             channels= int( fields[1])
             owing= float( fields[2])
             status= str( fields[3])
             mark= int( fields[4])
             code= fields[5]
             self.counter.add( Rectangle(theme, channels, owing, status, mark, code))

          theFile.close() 

    ##--------------------
    ## Demonstrator class
    ##   
    ##--------------------
    class Demonstrator():

       def __init__(self,filename):
          self.counter = Counter()
          self.reader = FileReader(filename, self.counter)
          self.reader.run()

       def Q1Answer(self):
          print(self.counter.question1())

       def newFile(self, filename):
          self.counter.reset() # throw away any old results
          self.reader = FileReader( filename, self.counter)
          self.reader.run()

    #----------------------------

    #----------------------------
    print("\n\t My Work","+"*30)
    #print("\nFirst calculating with the file reca.csv")
    d = Demonstrator("######.csv")
    d.Q1Answer()
```

This the imported module if that helps:

```
class Rectangle():

   def __init__(self, theme, channels, owing, status, mark, code):


      self.theme= theme
      self.channels= channels
      self.owing= owing
      self.status= status
      self.mark= mark
      self.code= code




   def getTheme(self):return self.theme
   def getChannels(self):return self.channels
   def getOwing(self):return self.owing
   def getStatus(self):return self.status
   def getMark(self):return self.mark
   def getCode(self):return self.code
```

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the exception. Clearly something is missing here, none of your classes take that many arguments.

Comment: Done the edits as requested

Comment: Your code indentation is all over the place. Noone can copy and paste this code to try to run it.

Comment: Did you restart the Python interpreter after making code changes to the error that threw the exception? Because the error is best explained if you either didn't restart or you have a stale `.pyc` file for the `rect.py` module lying about.

Comment: Your `Rectangle` class requires **6** positional arguments, not 5, so the exception message doesn't appear to match the code you posted.

Comment: Another possibility: a different `rect.py` file is being imported. Make sure that `import rect; print(rect.__file__)` points to the file you are expecting to import here.

Comment: yes i have done that, im having trouble with the indentation on the site i can seem to even move some of the text over, its a direct copy paste with it all then highlighted and using your add code button in the text editor. and ill double check your last comment thanks

Comment: Hey Martijn i think you solved it for me right there, i had a rec1.py file in the same folder, does python only read a part of the filename and if it matches import it? i had rect.py and rect1.py after removing rect1 from the folder the code works, experimenting, i put it back and named it to a random string and the code works ok still, seems that was my error all along!

Comment: cant thank you enough! was buggin me for ages

Comment: When importing, Python creates a `.pyc` bytecode cache file. If the original `.py` file is gone, the `.pyc` file suffices as that's the actual information Python needs to be able to run the code. It could be that the `.pyc` file is *newer* than your source code, in which case your source code is also ignored. Removing the `.pyc` file can help in that case.

Comment: I was looking through the files and found the pyc! Thanks martijn i learnt a lot from you today.